# Ruby/Rails: How to temporarily define what scope to call methods

Tags: ruby, module, include

I have a module:

```
module LiquidFilters
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def stylesheet_tag(stylesheet_file_path)
    stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_file_path
  end
end
```

And my spec:

```
describe LiquidFilters do
  describe "#stylesheet_tag" do
    it "should return the css file in an html (media=screen) tag" do
      helper.stylesheet_tag("/path/css").should match(/<link href="\/path\/css\.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text\/css"\s*\/>/)
    end
  end
end
```

But I get a **wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)** error:

```
Failures:
  1) LiquidFilters#stylesheet_tag should return the css file in an html (media=screen) tag
     Failure/Error: helper.stylesheet_tag("/path/css").should match(/<link href="\/path\/css\.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text\/css"\s*\/>/)
     wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./app/filters/liquid_filters.rb:16:in `stylesheet_tag'
     # ./spec/helpers/liquid_filters_spec.rb:13
```

I can see the problem is at `stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_file_path` in the `LiquidFilters` module -- the `stylesheet_link_tag` is supposed to call a [AssetTagHelper private method "stylesheet_tag"](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag), but it ends up calling `LiquidFilter`'s `stylesheet_tag` method.

## Question

**How do I force `stylesheet_link_tag` to call `AssetTagHelper`'s methods, and not `LiquidFilter`'s?**

*Note: I'd like to keep the method name `stylesheet_tag`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the `AssetTagHelper` module in a `Helper` class to avoid the method name override, like this:

```
require 'singleton'

module LiquidFilters
  class Helper
    include Singleton  
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  end

  def stylesheet_tag(stylesheet_file_path)
    Helper.instance.stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_file_path
  end
end
```

That way, your `stylesheet_tag` method won't get mixed up with the `AssetTagHelper`'s private method.

**Edit**

Based on your feedback, I guess this is the closest you get then:

```
module LiquidFilters
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  alias :old_stylesheet_tag :stylesheet_tag

  def stylesheet_tag(stylesheet_file_path, options = nil)
    if options
      old_stylesheet_tag(stylesheet_file_path, options)
    else
      stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_file_path
    end 
  end 
end
```

You basically override the private method, so I don't think there is any other alternative than proxying calls.

Comment: I got close! But I got this error: `undefined local variable or method 'config' for #<LiquidFilters::Helper:0xba3446c>`. I suppose it's because the Rails `config` isn't passed on to the class `Helper`. `config` is used by `stylesheet_link_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails's [`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_method_chain) could help:

```
module LiquidFilters
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def stylesheet_tag_with_liquid(stylesheet_file_path, options = nil)
    # if this got called with two arguments, proxy them to original
    if options
      stylesheet_tag_without_liquid(stylesheet_file_path, options)
    else
      stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_file_path
    end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    alias_method_chain :stylesheet_tag, :liquid
  end
end
```

While you still mask the original method, you can now proxy to it.

**EDIT:** moved `alias_method_chain` to `self.included` callback, so it won't be called before the module is actually included somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Got `Failure/Error: ... private method 'stylesheet_tag' called`. It seems that you can't `alias_method_chain` a private method?

Comment: My bad - I was still calling `helper.stylesheet_tag`.

Comment: This would technically work, but I was hoping to still be able to keep the `stylesheet_tag` method so I can call that as a filter. A filter, just in case you're not familiar with liquid, is something that the users of the app are exposed to, so it has to be simple.

I could have a completely different method name, like `stylesheet_html_tag` and it would work. However, I asked here to see if there was a way to still keep the same `stylesheet_tag` method name.

Comment: Ramon - this method means you do just call `stylesheet_tag`. `alias_method_chain :foo, :bar` replaces the existing `foo` method with `foo_without_bar`, and causes `foo` to call `foo_with_bar`. So Laas's code means that `stylesheet_tag` will call `_with_liquid` first, passing through to the appropriate function based on number of arguments.

Comment: Chowlett: hmm.. it's back to my problem when I first tried it then - `Failure/Error: helper.stylesheet_tag("/path/css").should.... private method 'stylesheet_tag' called`.

Comment: I found someone with a problem that I think is similar, but my Ruby powers haven't grown enough to understand it yet. http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192203

Comment: @Ramon - I found that link too, but until now did not think that through. If my updated code works, then it is basically that `alias_method_chain` has to be called on the receiver class, not the actual module it is defined in, which seems reasonable. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it when I read the link but it caused the same error for me. Thanks though, as the edited answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962467/ruby-rails-how-do-temporarily-define-what-scope-to-call-methods/5966038#5966038 works :)